# Is there a way to embed pictures from DROPBOX or just get the picture file itself and upload it to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, image, storage, dropbox-api

I'm building a website and need to store images in it. my database gives only 512mb and I'm planning to use more images than that. I taught of the idea to store the images into dropbox and using its API to get the images and embed them into my website.

Is this possible and if it is, how can I go by doing this?

I won't show some code because I don't even know if this is possible.

Also if you have an idea of storing the images into another database or another way feel free to answer. Basically I need a way to upload images at runtime (from my website or while my website is running but without changing the code) and after that I need to display the images to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You might try forwarding image to imgur or something similar and you'll probably get url back as return